# Protect and backup a file with passwords

Tags: password, password-store

Let's say that you have ~/passwords.txt file where you store all your passwords.

How to

1. Best secure the file, so that only you can read/write this file with some "master password"?
2. Securely backup this file (e.g. to flash drive)?

Which conditions should be fulfilled, so that this technique will be bullet-proof.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Which conditions should be fulfilled, so that this technique will be bullet-proof.

- Sane database layout (**not** a text file) and
- established safe cryptography. As much as important,
- ease of use, and little chance to do something bad by mistake.

Ideally, instead of just a master password, usage of a hardware token (like a Yubikey) to ensure safe encryption, even if someone should get to know your password.

So:

Clear job for a password manager, not a plain text file (and a proper database being what's encrypted, to avoid delimiter pitfalls): you want something using a well-tested cryptographic library to encrypt your passwords.

There's many popular password managers that are available across multiple platforms. All of them (at least the useful ones) have either trivial to backup single file databases, or a specific export/import/backup functionality.

People like [KeePassXC](https://keepassxc.org/download/#linux). I think it's good for beginners, so that'd be my recommendation. There's [KeePassDX](https://www.keepassdx.com/) as well, which is probably a good choice if you need passwords on your android phone. It has the same database format. Haven't tried it, but in general, doing this on android is probably safer than doing it on usual desktop Linux systems – Android's inter-application separation is pretty good, whereas processes running as the same user on POSIX-style Linux systems have practically no secrets from each other.

Comment: Is it even safer to store in the password some extra characters which I know on which places exactly they are? It's only cumbersome to delete them after pasting the password to the clipboard. What should the hacker do to hack my database? He has to guess only one password (master password for the db). Is somewhere description of it, I would like to believe it's very secure. I guess the master password should be strong.

Comment: it makes no sense. Either your computer is compromised, in which case an attacker would see the password you're actually using, or it's not, and then safely encrypted means safely encrypted, and adding your own crypto clutches (like adding characters) atop doesn't do any good.

Comment: The Keypass database format is well-documented, see the websites and source code repositories. The cryptographic methods are standard, and covered in standard crypto literature.